# Deeply nested strong parameters in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters

I have a `jsonb` column that stores json in my database and I am trying to use strong parameters to allow certain fields but cannot get it working.  When I do the following, I see all parameters as expected (duh!):

```
def daily_checkin_question_params
  params.require(:daily_checkin_question).permit!
end
```

But when I attempt to add the parameters I run into an issue.  The data is structured like this:

```
{
  question_type: 'single-select',
  name: 'Which describes your mood?',
  metadata: {
    question_data: {
      unit: 'mood',
      options: [
        { label: 'Happy', value: 'happy' },
        { label: 'Sad', value: 'sad' },
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

All fields work as expected other than the `value` param within the `options` array.  For some reason that is converted to `nil`.  When permitting all params (like above) this issue does not arise so I know it has to do with my strong parameters.

```
def daily_checkin_question_params
  params.require(:daily_checkin_question).permit(
    :question_type, :name, :position, :employee_id,
    metadata: [
      validation: [
        min: validation_params,
        max: validation_params,
        required: validation_params
      ],
      question_data: [
        :min, :max, :step, :unit, :total_stars, :allow_half_star,
        :multiline, options: [:label, :value]
      ]
    ]
  )
end
```

Comment: Show what's logged when you do: `logger.debug daily_checkin_question_params[:metadata][:question_data][:options]`